# Why is $\{X_nY_n \nrightarrow XY\} \subset \{X_n \nrightarrow X\} \cup \{Y_n \nrightarrow Y\}$ when $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converge almost surely?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Suppose that $X_n\overset{a.s.}{\to}X$ and $Y_n\overset{a.s.}{\to}Y$. Then, perhaps the easiest way to show that $X_nY_n \overset{a.s.}{\to} X Y $ is by showing that the event $\{X_nY_n \nrightarrow XY\}$has a measure zero. Then, if $\{X_nY_n \nrightarrow XY\} \subset \{X_n \nrightarrow X\} \cup \{Y_n \nrightarrow Y\}$, we are done as both $\{X_n \nrightarrow X\}$ and $\{Y_n \nrightarrow Y\}$ have measure zero, by assumption. Therefore my question is is that why is the event $\{X_nY_n \nrightarrow XY\}$ a subset of $\{X_n \nrightarrow X\} \cup \{Y_n \nrightarrow Y\}$? What is confusing me is that while for any $\omega \in \subset \{X_n \nrightarrow X\} \cup \{Y_n \nrightarrow Y\}$ we know that $X_n(\omega) \nrightarrow X(\omega)$ and $Y _n(\omega) \nrightarrow Y(\omega)$, how do we know, necessarily that then $X_n(\omega)Y_n(\omega) \nrightarrow X(\omega)Y(\omega)$? What is bugging me is the uncertainty that what if the $X_n$s and $Y_n$s could "cancel" each other out in such a way that $X_n(\omega)Y_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)Y(\omega)$?

Comment: You don't have to show that necessarily the product doesn't converge if one of the sequences don't - that's why it's a subset relation. You have to show that if $X_nY_n$ doesn't converge, then at least one of $X_n$ or $Y_n$ can't converge. But this is almost obvious in the complement - if both $X_n$ and $Y_n$ did converge, then so would $X_nY_n$.

Comment: On closer reading, you're also confusing $\cap$ and $\cup$ - $\omega \in \{X_n \not\to X\} \cup \{Y_n \not\to Y\}$ tells you that one of the two are not convergent at this $\omega$, not that both aren't convergent (which would be if $\omega$ lay in the intersection of the two events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega_1:=\{X_n\to X\}$ and $\Omega_{2}:=\{Y_n\to Y\}$. Then $\{X_n\to X\}\cap \{Y_n\to Y\}=\Omega_1\cap \Omega_2$. For each $\omega\in\Omega_1\cap \Omega_2$, $X_n(\omega)Y_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)Y(\omega)$, which implies that $\Omega_1\cap \Omega_2\subseteq \{X_nY_n\to XY\}$ or
$$
\{X_nY_n\not\to XY\}\subseteq \Omega_1^c \cup \Omega_2^c.
$$

---

To see that $\Omega_1\cap \Omega_2$ does not necessarily equal $\{X_nY_n\to XY\}$ consider the following example. $X_n(\omega')=1\{n\equiv 0 \mod 2\}$, $Y_n(\omega')=1\{n\equiv 1 \mod 2\}$, $X(\omega')Y(\omega')=0$, and $X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)$ and $Y_n(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ for each $\omega\in \Omega\setminus\{\omega'\}$. Here, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converge on $\Omega\setminus \{\omega'\}$, but $X_nY_n\to XY$ everywhere.

Comment: Does $X_nY_n\to XY$ everywhere because $X_n(\omega') = 0 \{n \equiv 1 \mod 2\}$ and  $Y_n(\omega') = 0 \{n \equiv 0 \mod 2\}$?

Comment: @EpsilonAway We have $Y_n(\omega')X_n(\omega')=0$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: Yes, but let me rephrase the question: While you haven't explicitly defined it, is it so that $X_n(\omega') \equiv 0 \{n \equiv 1 \mod 2\}$ (resp. for $Y_n$) for all $n$?

Comment: @EpsilonAway I see. There is no such a notation as $0\{\cdot\}$. You can write $X_n(\omega')=1-1\{n\equiv 0 \mod 2\}$. ($1\{\cdot\}$ is an indicator here.)

Comment: Ah, now I see! I wasn't first sure whether the $\{\}$ after the $1$s were meant as a conditional, like $x_n = 1: n \equiv 0 (\mod 2)$. But now I see, as it is nothing but an indicator r.v.